# Can an elliptic curve have the form y^2 ≡ x^2 + 2x + 2 mod 17?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm new to cryptography and the associated level of maths. I'm practising past papers for an exam and found the question:

> Show that the condition 4a^3 + 27b^2 ≠ 0 mod p is fulfilled
>   for the elliptic curve y^2 ≡ **x^2** + 2x + 2 mod 17.

Surely elliptic curves usually follow the format y^2 ≡ **x^3** + ax + b mod p?

The x^2 has thrown me on this - can anyone clarify if this looks like a typo?

Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: Surely the definition of an elliptic curve has been given in class. What is it?

Comment: Yes, it was given as: y^2 ≡ x^3 + ax + b mod p

Comment: You guessed it, what's in the question does not match your definition. My bets are on a typo.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case, but as my mathematical ability is very basic, I did not want to presume anything. Thanks @fgrieu

Comment: In fact, the question cannot possibly be correct as stated (even if a different curve model had been introduced in class): That curve has genus $0$, hence is (by definition) certainly not an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is a typo in the question on the past exam paper, and it should read y^2 ≡ x^**3** + 2x + 2 mod 17